# different behaviors of dynamic chart changes in 2.1.9 when compared with 2.1.3 dc.js

Tags: dc.js

I have observed different behaviors about the dynamic changes of charts after upgrading from dc.js 2.1.3 to 2.1.9.
As shown in the following GIFs:

[image] [image]

1. On the top pie chart (with dc 2.1.3), the orders of sectors are fixed and only the sizes of sectors change (which seems natural to me).
2. On the bottom pie chart  (with dc 2.1.9), the orders of sectors are automatically adjusted and sectors are re-arranged by the the sizes (Although the sectors are now nicely sorted, the colors are kind of messy).

Would there be a parameter to specify the corresponding behavior, if one wants to use the new release (2.1.9), but keep the dynamic chart changes as demonstrated in 2.1.3?
(if not about downgrading to previous version)

P.S.: the changes are triggered by clicking other charts, which are not shown in the GIFs.

Many thanks.

Comment: I'm not ignoring this, and I agree it would be great to support this. It will take a little time to research, though. In the meantime, could you please try your example with version 2.0.5 - this preserves the "classic" behavior of dc.js, and a lot changed in this area in the 2.1 series. (You could also try `chart.ordering(null)` but I'm not sure if it will help.)